# Simpel text-slideshow behaves weird

Tags: jquery, css

I have a basic slideshow in jQuery that works correctly except that when the content fades in it either fades in from the top or from the bottom. I have really no idea why this is happening. I basically want the text to stay in the center of the screen (both horizontally and vertically) and just fade out & in on place.

HTML:

```
<div id="open-menu">
            <div class="index">

                <div class="sp">
                    <h1>HEADING 1</h1>
          <p>Text</p>
                </div>

                <div class="sp">
                    <h1>HEADING 2</h1>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>

                <div class="sp">
                    <h1>HEADING 3</h1>
                    <p>Text</p>
        </div>

                <div class="sp">
                    <h1>HEADING 4</h1>
                    <p>Text</p>
        </div>

                <div class="sp">
                    <h1>HEADING 5</h1>
                    <p>Text</p>
        </div>

                <div class="sp">
                    <h1>HEADING 6</h1>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>

            </div>

   <div id="button-previous">prev</div>
     <div id="button-next">next</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#open-menu {
    position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
    background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#open-menu .index {
    position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 54%;
    left: 50%;
}

#open-menu .index h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

#open-menu .index p {
   margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
   font-size: 1.25rem;
   line-height: 2.2rem;
}

#center-2 {
     display: table;
     margin: 0 auto;
   font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.sp {margin-bottom: 60px;}
#button-previous {float: left;}
#button-next {float: right;}
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
            $('.sp').hide();    
            $('.active').show();

        $('#button-next').click(function(){
            $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    

                if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {

                    $('.sp').first().addClass('active');

                }

                else {

                    $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');

                }

            $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
            $('.sp').fadeOut();
            $('.active').fadeIn();

        });

        $('#button-previous').click(function(){
            $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    

                if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {

                    $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
                }

                else {

                    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
                }

            $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
            $('.sp').fadeOut();
            $('.active').fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dgy740g3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
            $('.sp').hide();    
            $('.active').show();

        $('#button-next').click(function(){

    $('.active').fadeOut('slow',function(){
       $(this).removeClass('active');
       if($(this).is(':last-child'))
       {
        $('.sp').first().addClass('active').fadeIn();
       }
       else
       {
        $(this).next().addClass('active').fadeIn();
       }
    });

        });

        $('#button-previous').click(function(){
            $('.active').fadeOut('slow',function(){
       $(this).removeClass('active');
       if($(this).is(':first-child'))
       {
        $('.sp').last().addClass('active').fadeIn();
       }
       else
       {
        $(this).prev().addClass('active').fadeIn();
       }
    });
        });
    });
```

updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/dgy740g3/1/

Answer (score 0):

By default, your elements are using `position: fixed`, which means they affect each other's position on the page. If you change them to `position: absolute`, they will no longer push each other around as their display on the page is changed.

The `position: absolute` is used to position them relative to the nearest parent element that does not have a `position: fixed` setting, so you'll also want to update the container element to `position: relative`.

```
.index {position: relative;}
.sp {margin-bottom: 60px; position: absolute;}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: ya his css also had some issues...initially i also though of using css to fix it. bt i jst did it with js.